# $(g_n) \rightarrow g $ uniformly where $g_n$ has finite discontinuities and $g$ is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

It seems that this should be possible. What I had in mind to show that it's possible is by modifying a function that converges to the Dirichlet function so that it's uniform convergent:

Let $\{r_1, r_2, ..., r_n \} $ be an enumeration of all the rationals in $[0,1]$.

define $g_n(x) = \{\frac{1}{n}, x=r_n,  $  $0,$ otherwise.$\}$

I'm just not completely sure if this counts as uniformly convergent.

This is for integrable, not necessarily Riemann integrable nor Lebesgue integrable

Thanks!

Comment: The functions  you defined converge uniformly to $0$. (For each $x \in [0,1]$, eventually $g_n(x)=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.)

Comment: The functions $g_n$ you're defining are all equal to zero except on a single point. So, all the integrals involved will exist and be equal to zero (including the one for $g$, assuming the limit exists).

Comment: O don't understand the last sentence. Do you want Riemann integrable or Lebesgue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible under the stronger assumption that the $ g_n $ are bounded. Indeed, then $ g $ is also bounded by uniform convergence, and by the usual argument, if all of the $ g_n $ are continuous at a point $ x $, then so is $ g $: given $ \epsilon > 0 $, pick $ N $ such that $ \|g - g_N\|_{\infty} < \epsilon/3 $, and pick $ \delta > 0 $ such that for all $ t $ such that $ |x - t| < \delta $, we have $ |g_N(x) - g_N(t)| < \epsilon/3 $. Then, for the same range of $ t $, we have

$$ |g(x) - g(t)| \leq |g(x) - g_N(x)| + |g_N(x) - g_N(t)| + |g(t) - g_N(t)| < \epsilon $$

so that $ g $ is continuous at $ x $. Since the countable union of finite sets is countable, the set of points $ x $ such that at least one of the $ g_n $ is discontinuous at $ x $ is countable; and at all other points, $ g $ is continuous by the above argument. Therefore, the discontinuity set of $ g $ is at most countably infinite; in particular, it has Lebesgue measure zero. By Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability, $ g $ must therefore be Riemann integrable.

If the $ g_n $ are not assumed to be bounded, then one has trivial counterexamples: fixing a function $ f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R $ with finitely many discontinuities and an infinite integral (for example, $ f(x) = 1/x $ for $ x > 0 $, $ f(x) = 0 $ for $ x = 0 $), we may simply choose $ g_n = f $ for all $ n $.